# MongoDB - MySQL SUM (CASE WHEN) Equivalent?

Tags: mongodb, sum

I'm trying to do some testing with Mongo, I have figured some of the simpler MySQL queries Mongo equivalent.

I have this query that is a little more complex that I need help with...

```
SELECT DISTINCT dims_user,
    COUNT(DISTINCT asset_name) AS asset_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT system_name) AS station_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN details ='viewed' then 1 Else 0 end) AS viewed_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN details Like 'Viewed Web%' then 1 Else 0 end) AS Web_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN details = 'ThumbView' then 1 Else 0 end) AS ThumbView_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN details Like 'Exported%' then 1 Else 0 end) AS Exported_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN details Like '%Print%' then 1 Else 0 end) AS Printed_count
FROM asset_log GROUP BY dims_user;
```

Comment: Uh... that's not good relational practice... the data in the `details` column should be normalized out - same goes for a NoSQL db design, column:action =(view|web|thumb|export|print), then you'd just switch to a group by action.

Comment: its a bunch of log files, i just got whats there 32 million records

Comment: Then [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) it once (if it's static - or establish a load/conversion process for repeating loads) so that it is normalized.  It'll significantly simplify what you're trying to do.

Comment: you'll probably have to do it using map reduce (summing, counting, grouping) unless you preprocess your data to allow simple queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Rudu here as you should try to break the details into keys of a mongo document.

The document might contain an object like this:

```
details:
{
  viewed: true
  thumb_view: true
  web_viewed: false
  exported: true
  ...
}
```

If you don't restructure the data, the query will require non-rooted regular expressions which are unable to use the indexing features of MongoDB.

However, regardless of if you decide to do that or not you will want to use map reduce for this. You could emit items that include the details during the map (either by processing them  with regular expressions or simply emiting the keys in restructured form) and sum them in the reduce phase.

You can read more about it in the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this link, it may help:

http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/12/09/sql-to-mongodb-an-updated-mapping/

It explains how to break up a SQL CASE WHEN statement and replace each piece of SQL with the new aggregation pipeline syntax. An example is below for the first case when in your statement:

```
{
  $project : {
    'viewed': {
        '$cond': [ 
            {'$eq': ['$details', 'viewed'] },
            1, // if true
            0] // else
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be below example useful for you.

Let's say you have following sample data.

```
db.sample.insert([
{
  "_id" : 27001,
  "assigned_to" : "abc@xyz.com",
  "priority" : "High"
}
,{
  "_id" : 27002,
  "assigned_to" : "jkdj@xyz.com",
  "priority" : "Low"
},
{
  "_id" : 27003,
  "assigned_to" : "abc@xyz.com",
  "priority" : "High"
}
]);
```

Use below aggregate query to get

1.Total Count

2.Count where assigend_to is "abc@xyz.com"

3.Count where priority is "High"

```
db.sample.aggregate({$group:{
                                 _id: 0,total:{$sum:1},
                                'assigned_to' : { $sum : { $cond: [ {  $eq: [ '$assigned_to' , 'abc@xyz.com' ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
                                'hight_priority' : { $sum : { $cond: [ {  $eq: [ '$priority' , 'High' ] }, 1, 0 ] } }
                              } 
                        } 
                      );
```

And You will get Expected result

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "total" : 3,
            "assigned_to" : 2,
            "hight_priority" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```