# MongoDB select as?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm trying to accomplish the equivalent of:

```
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(password) > 0, true, false) AS has_password
```

In mongodb, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing case-statement in mongodb aggregation framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494113/performing-case-statement-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is utilizing the `$project` operator of the Aggregation Framework:
Assumptions:

1. There is a collection named 'users' with 'username' and 'password' fields.
2. A 'missing' password is null (this can be anything actually - I used null just for the example).

`db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{$project: {username: 1, has_password: { $ne: [ "$password", null ] }}}])`

The point is projecting the result of some operator (which is boolean, such as $ne).