# Mongo aggregation: add conditional fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregtion pipeline with several stages. After those stages, the simplified result is like that:

```
{
    feature1: [{random: 125}],
    feature2: [{a:"fsfs", val: [125]}]
}
```

I want to add a new field `type` which is set based on these conditions:

- feature1.size > 0 and feature2.size > 0 then type = 'back'
- feature2.size > 0 then type = 'front'
- otherwise type = 'none'

The content of `feature1` and `feature2` arrays is not significant, the type is based on either the arrays are populated or not.

My idea is to use a `$addFields` stage with a `$cond` operator but I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494113/performing-case-statement-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/).

Something like

```
{
  "$addFields":{
    "type":{
      "$switch":{
        "branches":[
          {
            "case":{
              "$and":[
                {"$gt":[{"$size":"$feature1"},0]},
                {"$gt":[{"$size":"$feature2"},0]}
              ]
            },
            "then":"back"
          },
          {
            "case":{
             "$gt":[{"$size":"$feature1"},0]
            },
            "then":"front"
          }
        ],
        "default":"none"
      }
    }
  }
}
```