# MongoDB or SQL - Using RegEx to Create a New Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I'm wondering if there's a way in MongoDB or SQL to do something similar to this in Pandas:

```
df['Category'] = df.product.str.extract('(pork|chicken|tofu)')
```

I want to do this to create a new group in an aggregation pipeline then get the average protein content per group.

For example:

```
db.test.insert(
[
 { "my_id": {"Product": "Pork Soup", "Protein": 100.0 }},
 { "my_id": {"Product": "Duck Sandwich", "Protein": 1000.1 }},
 { "my_id": {"Product": "Chicken Roll", "Protein": 100.69 }},
 { "my_id": {"Product": "Disgusting Tofu", "Protein": 0.1 }},
 { "my_id": {"Product": "Cardboard Casserole", "Protein": 50.0 }},
])
```

Result:

```
{Category: "Pork", "Product": "Pork Soup", "Protein": 100.0 }
{Category: NA, "Product": "Duck Sandwich", "Protein": 1000.1 }
{Category: "Chicken", "Product": "Chicken Roll", "Protein": 100.69}
{Category: "Tofu", "Product": "Disgusting Tofu", "Protein": 0.1 }
{Category: NA , "Product": "Cardboard Casserole", "Protein": 50.0 }
```

I was looking at the conditional and case statements in posts such as  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494113/performing-case-statement-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework) but couldn't figure out a way to do this with RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's quite painfull to write. You can use **`$switch`** for this in a **`$project`** stage:

here is the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        "$project": {
            "w": {
                "$split": ["$my_id.Product", " "]
            },
            "Product": "$my_id.Product",
            "Protein": "$my_id.Protein"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "Product": 1,
            "Protein": 1,
            "Category": {
                "$switch": {
                    "branches": [{
                            "case": {
                                "$in": ["Pork", "$w"]
                            },
                            "then": "Pork"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$in": ["Chicken", "$w"]
                            },
                            "then": "Chicken"
                        },
                        {
                            "case": {
                                "$in": ["Tofu", "$w"]
                            },
                            "then": "Tofu"
                        }
                    ],
                    "default": "NA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

results in:

```
[
  {
    "Category": "Pork", "Product": "Pork Soup", "Protein": 100
  },
  {
    "Category": "NA", "Product": "Duck Sandwich", "Protein": 1000.1
  },
  {
    "Category": "Chicken", "Product": "Chicken Roll", "Protein": 100.69
  },
  {
    "Category": "Tofu", "Product": "Disgusting Tofu", "Protein": 0.1
  },
  {
    "Category": "NA", "Product": "Cardboard Casserole", "Protein": 50
  }
]
```

Here is the link where you can try the query: [mongoplayground.net/p/7M0oS_ZdmIq](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7M0oS_ZdmIq)

Comment: Looks good felix. I can see you've split the product string on whitespace. What if I've got a product called "pork-roll"?

Comment: @veronik yes that's the limit. Saddly mongodb doesn't support `$regex` in `$switch`... You can still add `pork-roll` to the `$in` array along with `Pork` but its not a very good solution

Comment: Thanks @felix. Appreciate it. Is it possible to do what I want in SQL?