# How to write switch/case condition in Mongodb $match aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection named **Projects**; In this collection, I have a field for project's ***currency*** and a field for ***price*** amount.

In Express search route, I have 2 variables called *USDamount* and *EURamount*. my question is that how I can search for match priced projects by USDamount when document's currency is 'USD' and search by EURamount when document's currency is 'EUR' and **so on for other currencies**(it means I need a switch/case instead of if/else)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without detailed information, in Aggregations you can use the switch statement [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) and in your queries it  look something like this:

```
db.getCollection("Projects").aggregate(
    [
        { $project:
            {price : 
                {$switch: {
                   branches: [
                      { case: {$eq: ['$currency', 'USD']}, then: '$USDAmount' },
                      { case: {$eq: ['$currency', 'EUR']}, then: '$EURAmount' } ],
                   default: 0
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Note: to produce a compound object including Currency and Amount, you could replace (I.E. '$USDAmount') with:

```
{'currency': '$currency', 'amount': '$USDAmount' }
```

Note that I have added a default price of 0; you will probably want to add a $match operator to the pipeline before the $project.

A [more complicated example can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494113/performing-case-statement-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Comment: Does it just filter the price filed or the whole of the result documents by price field? (according to using $project)

Comment: $project doesn't really run a filter.  A $project stage in a pipeline is a presentation stage.  If you think of a mongo pipeline as a series of functions, as opposed to a single SQL query, it makes more sense.  The $project operator does processing upon what is input to it.
This is just presenting a price; you could return a compound field within the various cases if you wanted, and you can return additional fields not dependent on the case.

Comment: It works but to get what we want, we need to filter $project results by adding a $match at the end of the pipeline. thank you, Dylan.

Comment: For performance reasons it is generally better to add the match statement before the projection.  Narrowing the number of documents affected by the projection means less data is processed during the match.

Comment: In real, I'm $matching result again by using the project's field result.

Comment: If performance is a real issue, you could put the case statement into the match before the projection, as well as afterwards.  But that involves writing the same functionality twice.

Comment: How to make $eq case insensitive?

Comment: I think { case: {$eq: [toUpper('$currency'), 'USD']}, then: '$USDAmount' }, would make this case-insensitive. I'm not sure, though, and don't have a Mongo prompt handy to test it. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#std-label-aggregation-expressions that document seems to say it would work.